# Attempted import error: '...' is not exported from '...' error after updating 'react-scripts' to version 2.0.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-scripts

I updated `react-scripts` package to version 2.0.0 and now I am getting the following error for importing classes:

```
Attempted import error: 'MyClass' is not exported from '...'
```

This is the code which gives me an error:

```
import {MyClass} from '...'
```

And the file which it is imported from:

```
class MyClass{

  constructor(){
    ...
  }

  ....
}

module.exports = {
  ...,
  MyClass: MyClass
}
```

Solution:
This is the code which fixed the problem:

```
export class MyClass{

  constructor(){
  }
}
```

Comment: looks like a typo when you're importing... should be "import {myClass} from '...' " whereas you've used 'MyClass'

Comment: That was a typo in my pos,t not in my code. Sorry. The problem is sth else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try exporting just the class without making it an object. Like: 
module.exports = MyClass;

Comment: It worked. Thank you. I followed these examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

Comment: glad to hear that.